# Rails API: Adding array of objects to json return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I'm using the built-in API with Rails 5.

I'm learning to write APIs with Rails and I'm trying to figure out how to add a property to my json return that is an array of objects.

I've got a model for Users and Posts.

What I would like to do is return all the posts associated with a users.

What I've done is in posts_controller.rb I've got a method that gets the userID form the URL and returns json that looks like:

`[{"id":1,"content":"My first post!","user":{"id":1,"firstname":"Jody","lastname":"White","email":"t@t.com","fullname_firstname_first":"Jody White"}},{"id":2,"content":"Rails School is awesome!","user":{"id":1,"firstname":"Jody","lastname":"White","email":"t@t.com","fullname_firstname_first":"Jody White"}}]`

But what I want is to return that looks like this:

```
{
    firstname: "Jody",
    lastname: "White",
    email: "whatever",
    posts: [{
        "id":1,"content":"My first post!"
        },
        {
            "id":2,"content":"Rails School is awesome!"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I go about, or can I, getting the data to return like that?

user.rb model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :fullname_firstname_first

  has_many :posts

  def fullname_firstname_first
    fullname_firstname_first = firstname + " " + lastname
  end
end
```

post.rb model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users, include: :posts
  end

  # GET /users/1
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render json: @user, include: :posts
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your models, showing the associations involved, please? We probably don't need to see full models.

Comment: @jaydel Updated the post with the models.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you defined this structure:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
```

You could achieve a structure like you wanted with the  Active Record serialization method `to_json`. The use would be in a `respond_to` block in your controller.

`format.json { render json: @users, include: :posts }`

So your `UsersController` would look something like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # all users with all their posts 
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @users, include: :posts }
    end
  end

  def show
    # single user and their posts
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @user, include: :posts }
    end
  end
end
```

**Update**

Instead of using the `repond_to` block you can alternatively use:

`render json: @users, include: :posts`

Your controller will then look like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # all users with all their posts 
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users, include: :posts
  end

  def show
    # single user and their posts
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render json: @user, include: :posts
  end
end
```

Comment: In my show method I changed `render json: @user` to `render json: @user.posts` and I'm getting the same format as my original post. If it matters I'm using Active Model Serializer.

Comment: I'm using Rails 5 and it looks like respond_to is deprecated? I found a post saying if I wanted to use respond_to I needed to add `include ActionController::MimeResponds` to application_controller.rb but when I do I get `"status":406,"error":"Not Acceptable","exception":"#\u003cActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat\u003e"`

Comment: @Christian-G I've got my controller and methods looking like yours now but I'm not getting the posts included in the response.  See my edited original post for my models if that helps.

Comment: What does your controller look like now?

Comment: @Christian-G My original post has been updates with a partial of the users_controller.rb file

Comment: @Christian-G I figured it out. Using ActiveModelSerializer I can do `render json: @user.as_json(include: :posts)`. And that returns in the format I'm looking for! Thanks!